# How does web component relate to the composite pattern in JS?

Tags: javascript, web-component, composite

I am reading Javascript composite pattern, and wondering if the new web component lends itself to this pattern. After a search on google I found very few article directly talking about this topic. How do the two relate? Can someone point out a course or article on this?

Comment: [slots](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots) allow to use composition

Comment: but slots only gives you composition power for rendering, not other benefits in terms of what composite pattern promises, like unifying interface, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are diffrent way to implement the composite pattern to Web Components.

A simple way is to define a base class that will expose some methods (your unified interface), 
then define different Custom Elements that will use an extension of the base class.

```js
//Create a base class with unified methods (or props, or display)
class BaseElement extends HTMLElement {
  sayYourName() {
    console.log( "hello, I'm a " + this.localName )
  }
}

//Define differents elements that extends the Base one
class Type1 extends BaseElement {}
customElements.define( 'type-1', Type1 )
class Type2 extends BaseElement {}
customElements.define( 'type-2', Type2 )

//Call the common method against diffrent types of custom elements
var elems = document.querySelectorAll( 'div *' )
elems.forEach( e => e.sayYourName() )
```

```html
<div>
  <type-1>Type1</type-1>
  <type-2>Type2</type-2>
</div>
```

Comment: don't forget to use ``super.connectedCallback()`` if a derived class has the method itself (unless you don't want to call the super method)

Comment: This is a wonderful example. However, with all the bulky and clunky DOM template and shadow and slotted nodes, web components seem too dirty to be freely compatible with the composite patterns. Is it designed to be compositable? Could you please also point a good resource to learn in depth this topic? Thank you.

Comment: The reason why custom elements are compositable relies on their object nature. Every resource about composite Javascipt is applicable.